# Wikipedia api fulltext search to return articles with title, snippet and image

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I've been looking for a way to query the wikipedia api based on a search string for a list of articles with the following properties:

- Title
- Snippet/Description
- One or more images related to the article.

I also have to make the query using jsonp.

I've tried using the list=search parameter

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&prop=images&format=json&srsearch=test&srnamespace=0&srprop=snippet&srlimit=10&imlimit=1

But it seems to ignore the prop=images, I've also tried variations using the prop=imageinfo and prop=pageimages. But they all give me the same result as just using the list=search.

I've also tried action=opensearch

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=test&limit=10&format=xml

Which gives me exactly what I want when i set format=xml, but returns a simple array of page titles when using format=json and therefore fails because of the jsonp requirement.

Is there another approach to doing this? I'd really like to solve this in a single request rather than make the first search request and then a second request for the images using titles=x|y|z

Comment: You can't use a `list` and a `prop` query together.

Comment: So there is no way of doing this in one request? Seems like a pretty standard query to make.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As Bergi suggested, using generators is the way to go here. Specifically what I would do:

- use [`list=search`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search) as a generator, to get the list of articles
- use [`prop=pageimages`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages#API) to get a representative image for each article
- use [`prop=extracts`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts#API) to get a description for each article

The whole query could look like this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrsearch=test&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max

Comment: Thank you, this also solved a new requirement I had, by giving me a property for controlling the length of the snippet/extract.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried using the list=search parameter, but it seems to ignore the prop=images

If you want to retrieve any [properties](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties), you need to specify a list of pages for which you want to get these; e.g. by using the `titles=`, `pageids=`, or `revids=` parameters. You didn't send any, so you did not get a result for the `prop=images`.

If you did use [`api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=test&prop=images&titles=test`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=test&srnamespace=0&srprop=snippet&prop=images&titles=test&format=jsonfm) you would have gotten the search results for `test` *and* the images of the `Test` page.

You can however also use the collection that the `list` query generates for your property query, using the `list` module as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators). The query would look like
[`api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=test&gsrnamespace=0&gsrprop=snippet&prop=images`](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=test&gsrnamespace=0&gsrprop=snippet&prop=images&format=jsonfm). Unfortunately, it does not yield the attributes that the list contained, but only used the pageids for a basic property query.

Using two queries is probably the way to go. Btw, I'd recommend to use the [`pageimages` property](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages), it will likely give you the best results.