# Wikipedia api get image, full text and snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am using the following to get the title, snippet and link to Wikipedia article after a search result using their API:

```
   $("#wiki").on('click', function(e) {
      var q = $(this).data('subject');
      $.getJSON("http://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?", {
        srsearch: q,
        action: "query",
        list: "search",
        format: "json"
      }, function(data) {
        $("#results").empty();
        $("#results").append("<p>Results for <b>" + q + "</b></p>");
        $.each(data.query.search, function(i, item) {
          $("#results").append("<div><a href='http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + encodeURIComponent(item.title) + "'>" + item.title + "</a><br>" + item.snippet + "<br><br></div>");
        });
      });
    });
```

HTML

```
<button id="wiki" data-subject="<?php echo $title(); ?>">Wikipedia</button>
<output id="results"></output>
```

I tried to follow [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891076/wikipedia-api-fulltext-search-to-return-articles-with-title-snippet-and-image) and answers to see if I can solve myself but with no luck, also tried to [follow this example](http://www.9bitstudios.com/2014/03/getting-data-from-the-wikipedia-api-using-jquery/).

> How can I implement a query for full articles, image and snippet using
>   the js I am using?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rbpaj2pf/ What's the issue you have?

Comment: I know, yet as per the question: "How can I implement a query for full articles, image and snippet using the js I am using?"

Comment: So your question is basically 'I've got a wheel and a screwdriver, how do I build a car?'

Comment: more like how can I improve the car I've built?

Comment: The API has some documentation on how to get different props in queries -> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query

Comment: You can use the [API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox) to experiment with your query. What you probably want is to use the search module as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) and then you can use other API modules to process the list of titles returned by it.